# We have lost permissions on the topology schema

Tags: postgis, postgresql

We have a PostgreSQL database with PostGIS, with the following versions:

```
 PostgreSQL 10.21 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12), 64-bit
```

```
                                                                                                                                         postgis_full_version

 POSTGIS="2.4.5 r16765" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.7.3-CAPI-1.11.3 b50468f" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.4, released 2017/06/23" LIBXML="2.9.1" LIBJSON="0.12.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.0" (core procs from "2.4.4 r16526" need upgrade) RASTER (raster procs from "2.4.4
 r16526" need upgrade)
```

We are getting this error when trying to do a pg_dump:

```
pg_dump: last built-in OID is 16383
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: identifying extension members
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for schema topology
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE "topology"."topology" IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

We strongly believe that we have not upgraded PostGIS (we are going to though, to 2.5 when we upgrade to PostgreSQL 12), so we may have run one of the testing commands for the upgrade in the production database without realising it.

The things is, we need that access back. I have tried the following commands:

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA topology to <user>;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA topology TO <user>;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA topology TO <user>;
```

But our users do not have permission either! I have tried with the superuser provided by RDS and our own user, so not sure at all what is going on. Any idea?

### Update 1

I have run the following query:

```sql
SELECT n.nspname AS "Name",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(n.nspowner) AS "Owner",
  pg_catalog.array_to_string(n.nspacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges",
  pg_catalog.obj_description(n.oid, 'pg_namespace') AS "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
WHERE n.nspname !~ '^pg_' AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
ORDER BY 1;
```

And I have got:

```
    Name    |     Owner      |         Access privileges         |       Description
 topology   | rdsadmin       |                                   | PostGIS Topology schema
```

### Update 2

I already tried to log in as `postgres` user, but it does not work either, same error.

Comment: According to [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html), "if the 'Access privileges' column is empty for a given object, it means the object has default privileges ... **Default privileges always include all privileges for the owner** ..." What user are you running pg_dump with? From above, rdsadmin should have access. From update 2, is pg_dump failing when postgres user runs it? Do you need to [upgrade PostGIS extension](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_administration.html#soft_upgrade_extensions)?

Comment: I'm running the pg_dump with the same user we use on our app. I have tried with postgres and it does not work either. The problem with rdsadmin is that we cannot access that user (controlled by AWS). Not sure what we have run to get to this point. One week ago everything was fine. I think we don't need to run a postgis upgrade (I know we are using and old version, but that should not be the root of this problem)

Comment: Your full version string says you have PostGIS 2.4.5 installed and shows the notes that core procs and raster procs 'from "2.4.4 r16526" need upgrade'. Doesn't that mean that your installed extension in the database and the software libraries installed don't match. That suggests the extensions need to be upgraded to match software updates that were done.